# CRM 4.0 Open specified view with navbar

Tags: view, hyperlink, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have a problem with opening the link from a view in crm.

When I open a view in crm it looks like this:

[image: Normal View]

When I open a copied link of a view i looks somehow likes this:

[image: Opened form a view-link]

As you can see, the navigation bar left and the bar above the view aren't shown.

The link, I have looks something like this:

```
http://server/organisation/_root/homepage.aspx?etc=2&viewid=%7b61300000-0202-0487-00AA-000010007094%7d
```

How do I have to modify my link, or are there any additional parameters for it to open a view like in pic 1 ?

Thanks Karl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your site map.config and verify your copied link has the proper settings to show the navigation.